# JSON Parsing Error: invalid JavaScript property identifier character

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have downloaded json string from internet by using `HttpClient`:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) {
    var json = client.GetStringAsync(uri).Result;
    ....
}
```

the string have some errors (I haven't got access to web server so I cannot change anything there):

```
....
"phone": "01595 692506",
"miles": 6,
383.68,
"name": "Name",
....
```

The problem appears in miles. The value is formatted to `6,383.68` with comma so the json parser thinks it's another property.
The error I'm getting is:

```
Invalid JavaScript property identifier character: .. Path 'data[0].miles' ...
```

I tried to download it with `WebClient` with no luck and I also tried to change the `JsonSerializerSettings` settings but it didn't work too.

Please help

Comment: Change the `"miles": 6,383.68` string to `"miles": 6383.68`

Comment: That's what I'm getting from web server I have no access to it so I cannot change it.

Comment: The web server result string is a always a text plan?, if Yes, replace all text after colon separation in a quotation marks, something like this `"miles": "6,383.68"`, use a regular expression for that.

Comment: That's what I'm doing now but I don't think so this is a right way to do it.

Comment: It's not right way, but as you told me, that web server is not in your business.